# Why do I need to specify schema for JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Here is the datasource spec in the application.properties

```
spring.dw.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/file:~/developer/myprojects;schema=DW;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=true
spring.dw.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.dw.datasource.username=me
spring.dw.datasource.password=p
spring.dw.datasource.platform=h2
```

In my configuration I do:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
    //...

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.dw.database")
    public DataSource dwDatasource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

In one of my services methods I do:

```
@Autowired
public DataSource dwDatasource;

public void run() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dwDatasource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE1 (STRING1, STRING2) VALUES ('TEST4', 'TEST2')");
        System.out.println("<<run()");
    }
```

I get:

```
 StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE1 (STRING1, STRING2) VALUES ('TEST4', 'TEST2')]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SAMPLETABLE1" not found; SQL statement:
```

However, if I do:

```
public void run() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dwDatasource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO DW.SAMPLETABLE1 (STRING1, STRING2) VALUES ('TEST4', 'TEST2')");
        System.out.println("<<run()");
    }
```

All works.

So question, is why should I have to specify schema

Answer (score 2):

From the H2 Documentation: [schema](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_schema)

> The default
>   schema is used in statements where no schema is set explicitly. The
>   default schema for new connections is `PUBLIC`.

You can specify however the default schema to use, from the same documentation:

> This setting can be appended to the database URL:
>   `jdbc:h2:test;SCHEMA=ABC`